# Server high availability and redundancy

Tags: server, hosting

I'm currently running a webserver with some websites and a webapp. i'm quite paranoid about the server shutting down and not being able to have another server online just in time so the customer didn't notice it.

Is there any solution to run a second server and replicate the 2 continuously and when the "master" server dies the other one takes over?
which software packets would you recommend?

Comment: Higher reliability = higher budget. Is your organization prepared to budget a reasonable amount?

Comment: yes for sure. We have the equipment, the only part that is missing is the configuration of the redundancy..

Comment: What kind of application? Which backend does it use? Replicating databases is not *trivial*, and has a lot of pitfalls. What is the actual uptime requirement? A redundant setup is not twice the cost, as configuration complexity rises quite a bit.